# PHP upload script causing Error 500 when page is opened

Tags: php

I have one page where I can upload files. On my localhost everything work fine but on the shared host doesn't work and when I load the page it crashing and showing `Error 500 - Internal Server Error`.

The only different's between local configuration and configuration on the host is `eAccelerator` which is enabled by default on the shared host.

I have tried to create `php.ini` on the host and disable it but no luck so far. In the `.htaccess` i've put:

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /home/myuser/public_html/php.ini
</IfModule>
```

note: `myuser` is not my real user.. I've changed it just for here.
Then in `php.ini` I put this but on the `phpinfo()` is still showing that is enabled.

```
eaccelerator.enable 0
eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```

Sadly but there is not errors anywhere so I don't know what exactly going on here. No errors in cPanel. No errors in the directory with the file. No errors when I try with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`.

When I remove this portion of code the page is loaded and no errors. So the problem is in the code + eaccelator. Here is the code which is located above the HTML form in the same file.

```
if (array_key_exists("add", $_POST)) {
$pdo = Database::connect();

    $allowedFileTypes = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/bmp');

    $uploadFolder = "uploads/";

    $totalFiles = 0;
    $files = (object)[
        'file_1' => (object)['name' => ''],
        'file_2' => (object)['name' => ''],
        'file_3' => (object)['name' => '']
    ];

    $query = "INSERT INTO file_upload (
            `file_title`, `file_program`, `file_subject`, `file_1`, `file_2`, `file_3`, `uploaded_by`, `upload_date`
            ) VALUES (
            :file_title, :file_program, :file_subject, :file_1, :file_2, :file_3, :uploaded_by, NOW()
            )";
    $queryPrepare = $pdo->prepare($query);

    foreach (array_keys($_FILES) as $file) {
        $filesInCurrentInput = count(array_filter($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']));
        if (!$filesInCurrentInput) {
            continue;
        }

        $totalFiles += $filesInCurrentInput;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $filesInCurrentInput; $i++) {
            if ($_FILES[$file]['error'][$i]) {
                continue;
            }

            $type = $_FILES[$file]['type'][$i];
            if (!in_array($type, $allowedFileTypes)) {
                throw new Exception("File type not allowed.");
            }

            $oldName = $_FILES[$file]['name'][$i];
            $getEndOfFile = explode(".", $oldName);

    $extension = end($getEndOfFile);
            $name = hash("md5", uniqid(rand(), true)) . '.' . $extension;
            $temporaryFile = $_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'][$i];

            if (!move_uploaded_file($temporaryFile, $uploadFolder.$name)) {
                throw new Exception("An error occured while trying to upload a file.");
            } else {
                $files->$file->name .= $name . ',';
            }
        }
    }

    if (!$totalFiles) {
        throw new Exception("You must attach files to the lesson.");
    }

    $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['file_title']);
    $file_program = htmlspecialchars($_POST['file_program']);
    $file_subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['file_subject']);
    $uploaded_by = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user_username']);

    $queryPrepare->bindValue(":file_title", $title);
    $queryPrepare->bindValue(":file_program", $upload_program);
    $queryPrepare->bindValue(":file_subject", $upload_subject);

    $queryPrepare->bindValue(":file_1", trim($files->file_1->name, ','));
    $queryPrepare->bindValue(":file_2", $files->file_2->name);
    $queryPrepare->bindValue(":file_3", $files->file_3->name);        
    $queryPrepare->bindValue(":uploaded_by", $uploaded_by);
    $queryPrepare->execute();

    echo "<p class='bg-success text-center'>File added successfully.</p>";  
}
```

The form is simple form with few fields.. nothing special there. Any help on this?

Comment: As I wrote above -> there is nothing in the error log which I have in `cPanel`

Comment: `$files = (object)[
        'file_1' => (object)['name' => ''],
        'file_2' => (object)['name' => ''],
        'file_3' => (object)['name' => '']
    ];` could be a problem.

Comment: What can be the problem with this?

Comment: As I read, `eaccelator` stores the php code in shared memory. So something in this code exceed the shared memory or I'm wrong?

Comment: Depending on your version of PHP you need to assign Arrays to variables like `$ary = array();`.

Comment: I commented this `$files = (object)[ 'file_1' => (object)['name' => ''], 'file_2' => (object)['name' => ''], 'file_3' => (object)['name' => ''] ];` and page loaded. So this is the problem. Can you tell me how to change it exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this:

```
$files = (object)[
    'file_1' => (object)['name' => ''],
    'file_2' => (object)['name' => ''],
    'file_3' => (object)['name' => '']
];
```

To this and try to reload the page:

```
$files = (object)array(
        'file_1' => (object)array('name' => ''),
        'file_2' => (object)array('name' => ''),
        'file_3' => (object)array('name' => '')
);
```